# Need help in picking part of subject value from the Googlesheet by Appscript

Tags: sourceforge-appscript

I need to take part of the subject from a sheet pivot. I have tried the below way. The script is fetching the value, but it's skipping one raw in the loop.

The appscript should have respective supplier name in the the subject, as per its there in the emailbody. but its skipping on[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkkng.png)e iteration in the loop.